# WPF: How do I get only Time from textbox?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, datetime, textbox

I have a datatable with a column Total time active:`Total` which I want to filter on a minimal and maximal time e.g. show only active times between 00:02:00 and 00:30:00. My Stored Procedure works with these START and END times to filter.

In my WPF app i have a textbox and want to use this to filter said table.

(note, these aren't times of a day just times in general, i could be over 24 hours.)

What I found was that I need to convert the textbox string to DateTime, but I'm not sure how to do this since I'm very new to databases and WPF.
In xaml I tried using:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Activefrom"
    Text="{Binding Path=TotalStart,  StringFormat=' HH:mm:ss '}"/>
```

And in the code-behind converting the string with:

```
DateTime dateTimeStart = DateTime.ParseExact(Activefrom.Text, "HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

but i get the error:

```
System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'
```

Since it's times over 24 hours I'm not sure if I should use `DATETIME` but I tried it anyway since in this case the table doesn't go over 24 hours.

How can I bind the textbox as `Time` so I can use my SP to filter a datatable on times only

Comment: Look into using a [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you should have a look at the [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2) struct instead of DateTime. Also, I would probably split the input into one textbox for number of hours and one for number of minutes (depending on the range of duration times in your data).

Answer (score 0):

Read value from your TextBox:

then try to covert to `DateTime`, then to `Time` your value from `TextBox`:

```
string s = Activefrom.Text; // "22/11/2010  07:00:00 AM";
var dt = DateTime.Parse(s);
var time = dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Output:

```
07:00:00 // If TextBox has the following value: "22/11/2010  07:00:00 AM";
```